# Create arg string from ArgumentParser parsed args in Python

Tags: python, argparse

If I have an `argparser.ArgumentParser`, plus a namespace returned from `parser.parse_args`, is there a simple way to convert the namespace back into a list of argv such that they could be passed back to the program? Essentially, is there an inverse function of parse_args?

An example scenario:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--example', type=int, default=0)
args = parser.parse_args(argv)

args.example *= 2
new_argv = parser.generate_argv(args)
```

So if I call:

```
python my_program.py --example 1
```

I would want back:

```
new_argv = ['--example', '2']
```

Comment: I don't think there is; the `type` of an argument can be any arbitrary conversion function, you'd have to create an inverse for each of those.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can't you access whatever you're trying to call more directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we get too far into this question, lets be clear.  `args=parser.parse_args()` is the same as `args=parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])`.  But I can imagine cases where you like to know what `sys.argv[1:]` would produce some arbitrary `args`.  Maybe for testing, maybe for driving someone else's code.

There isn't any code in `argparse` that does this.  But for a limited set of cases you could take information from the defined Actions, and create a plausible `sys.argv`.

```
In [432]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [433]: parser.add_argument('--example', type=int, default=0)
Out[433]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--example'], dest='example', nargs=None, const=None, default=0, type=<type 'int'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

The list of defined Actions:

```
In [435]: parser._actions
Out[435]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['--example'], dest='example', nargs=None, const=None, default=0, type=<type 'int'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]
```

select the one of interest, and look at some of its attributes:

```
In [436]: a1=parser._actions[-1]
In [437]: a1.type
Out[437]: int
In [438]: a1.default
Out[438]: 0
```

Now generate `args`:

```
In [439]: args=parser.parse_args(['--example','1'])    
In [440]: args
Out[440]: Namespace(example=1)
In [441]: args.example *= 2
```

A simple example of creating a list using the new `args` and information from the Action.  Obviously the working code needs to deduce which action to use.  For the most common types `str()` is enough.

```
In [442]: if args.example != a1.default:
   .....:     print(['--example',str(args.example)])
   .....:     
['--example', '2']
```

Or I could play with the `metavar` attribute, and the `usage` formatter:

```
In [445]: a1.metavar=str(args.example)
In [446]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipython2.7 [-h] [--example 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up in a situation needing this, and here was my solution.  It assumes that you know what positional arguments are expected.  Definitely not foolproof, but it works for me.

```
def simulate_args_from_namespace(n, positional=[]):
    """ check an argparse namespace against a module's get_args method.
    Ideally, there would be something built in to argparse, but no such luck.
    This tries to reconstruct the arg list that argparse.parse_args would expect
    """
    arg_list = [[k, v] for k, v in sorted(vars(n).items())]
    argparse_formatted_list = []
    for l in arg_list:
        ####  deal with flag arguments (store true/false)
        if l[1] == True:
            argparse_formatted_list.append("--{}".format(l[0]))
        elif l[1] == False or l[1] is None:
            pass  # dont add this arg
        # add positional argments
        elif l[0] in positional:
            argparse_formatted_list.append(str(l[0]))
        # add the named arguments
        else:
            argparse_formatted_list.append("--{}".format(l[0]))
            argparse_formatted_list.append(str(l[1]))
    return argparse_formatted_list
```

Comment: `if l[1] == True` also matches arguments whose value is the integer `1` (i.e., it treats a non-flag argument as a flag argument), I added an `isinstance(l[1], bool)` check guarding it. Also, arguments with internal hyphens aren't treated properly, e.g. `--max-time` appears as the key `"max_time"` which then gets translated as the `--max_time`, in my case I changed `"--{}".format(l[0])` to `"--{}".format(l[0].replace("_", "-")`

Answer (score 0):

delete args from parser.parse_args(args)

args[1] == example

args[2] == string number

args.example == int number

```
from sys import argv
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--example', type=int, default=0 )
args = parser.parse_args()
print ([argv[1],args.example*2])
```

then

```
python my_program.py --example 1
>>>['--example', 2]
```

Comment: I'm looking for a general answer, not one for this specific example.

Comment: @BenMorris what is exactly do you need??  :D